# How does AWS EC2 generate CA signed certs lively?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How does AWS EC2 generate CA signed certs lively as you know there are so many EC2 instance out there ?

Comment: Which "CA signed certs" are you referring to? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: When we create an EC2 instance, the AWS configuration console can prompt user to download a private cert which i was referring to. How AWS generate different certs for different EC2 instance at scale

Comment: I believe you might be thinking of SSH private keys.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 never generates any SSL/TLS certificates on it's own. You can request a certificate for CloudFront or a load balancer, and it will be automatically issued, but in this case CloudFront or load balancer will terminate SSL itself.

It is possible to create an image (AMI) that will create/get/assign an SSL certificate on boot or at runtime, but this will have nothing to do with AWS.

Comment: When we create an EC2 instance, the AWS configuration console can prompt user to download a private cert which i was referring to. How AWS generate different certs for different EC2 instance at scale ?

Comment: When you create an EC2 instance you're asked for SSH key, **not** SSL certificate.